# PowerShell variable between two Jenkins scripts

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

**Context:**

Jenkins freestyle project with two PowerShell tasks. So Jenkins is doing two scripts, called by two separated processes.
It should avoid merge into one PowerShell task.

**Goal:**

I need to use a variable set in task 1 into task 2. This variable can be set with complex type, **for example**

Script 1:

```
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
```

Script 2:

```
$sw.Stop()
Write-Output "$($sw.Elapsed) ms"
```

**Questions:**

Is it possible to do this, with PowerShell behavior (like a "general" scope)?
Or with Jenkins behavior, with some Jenkins or PowerShell plugin options?

I presume it is impossible with "running" objects, and I should serialize variable (obviously limitation with serializable objects ;) ) into Jenkins workspace and deserialize from script 2.

I use EnvInject plugin, but you can modify or add vars during build tasks to send them to next tasks, this is why I'm thinking about custom serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Pick a shared location for temporary files that both tasks can access.
- Use PowerShell's `Export-CliXml` cmdlet to serialize the variables of interest to a (temporary) file and `Import-CliXml` to deserialize them.

As you state, "running" objects - instances of `[Diagnostics.Stopwatch]` being one example - will not deserialize faithfully - PowerShell will deserialize them as *emulations* of the original type based on general-purpose type `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]` with properties containing *static* copies of the values of the original instance (and no *methods* at all).

Comment: Is it possible to deserialize items in original type, maybe by following some restrictions?
I tried with a custom type referenced on a custom DLL (a simple model class), seems not work.

Comment: It depends on the specific type. If an instance can be recreated from just its public property values, it should work.